# Enviar form com ajax e retornar erros em uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando algumas bibliotecas do Boostrap, como a dos balões de alert, e gostaria de mostrar eles dependendo do resultado AJAX, como posso enviar um post com AJAX e retornar os erros/sucessos na divs, neste caso é melhor retornar em JSON ou plain text, visto que os erros são independentes?

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="teste" />
<input type="submit" name="post" />
</form>
```

A parte back-end (PHP) já está feita, e retornaria JSON, ex:

> Error: JSON => {"error":"1","nome":"incorreto"}

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
<p>O form contém erros bla bla</p>
</div>
```

> Sucesso: JSON => {"error":"0"}

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade in">
<p>Salvo com sucesso!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o seu retorno você pode mostrar as mensagens de sucesso,atencao,erro ou qualquer outra que deseje.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var msg = function(alerta, texto) {
  var resposta = '';
  $(".resposta").empty();

  switch (alerta) {
    case 'sucesso':
      resposta = "<div class='alert msg btn-success text-center' role='alert'>" +
        "   <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>&times;</a>" + texto + "</div>";
      break;
    case 'atencao':
      resposta = "<div class='alert msg btn-warning text-center' role='alert'>" +
        "   <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>&times;</a>" + texto + "</div>";
      break;
    case 'erro':
      resposta = "<div class='alert msg btn-danger text-center' role='alert'>" +
        "   <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>&times;</a>" + texto + "</div>";
      break;
    default:
      console.warn('Opção de alerta inválido.');
  }

  $(".resposta").append(resposta);

  $(".msg").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
};

$("#sucesso").click(function() {
  msg('sucesso', "Mensagem de sucesso!");
});


$("#atencao").click(function() {
  msg('atencao', "Mensagem de atenção!");
});


$("#erro").click(function() {
  msg('erro', "Mensagem de erro!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="resposta"></div>

<button type="button" id="sucesso" class="btn btn-success">Sucesso</button>
<button type="button" id="atencao" class="btn btn-warning">Sucesso</button>
<button type="button" id="erro" class="btn btn-danger">Sucesso</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado ,pela resposta, mas como seria o envio com ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Costumo usar algo assim:

```html
<div id="alertaConflito" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <strong id="vaimsg"></strong>
</a></div>
```

Javascript:

```js
jQuery("#vaimsg").html("Mensagem de Erro ou Sucesso");
$("#alertaConflito").show("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu sempre faço assim:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://suaUrl.com',
    data: {
        nomeValor: 'Valor para enviar para o servidor',
        outroValor: 133434
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.error === 1) {
            alert("Nome: " + data.nome);
        } else if(data.error === 0) {
            alert("Nenhum erro encontrado");
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
```